# d3.layout.histogram() and attributes don't work in v4

Tags: d3.js

I would like to "convert" a D3.js v3 based code to D3.js v4.

I don't know what I have to change in the following code that it doesnt display any error:

```
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
                        .bins(resolution)
                        .frequency(0)
                        (results);
```

I know that in d3.js v4 there isn't something like `d3.layout.histogram()` - I only found `d3.histogram()` in the API. But how do I change the "syntax" of line 2-4 in order to make it working with v4? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](https://swizec.com/blog/histogram-d3v3-d3v4/swizec/7145) we have the following list of differences between histogram layout in d3v3 and d3v4:

> - `d3.layout.histogram` becomes `d3.histogram`
> - `.bins` becomes `.thresholds`
> - `d3.scale.linear` becomes `d3.scaleLinear`
> - `d.x+d.dx` becomes `d.x1`
> - `d.y` becomes `d.length`
> - `d.dx` becomes `d.x1-d.x0`

More detailed explanations from [d3v4 changelog](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#arrays-d3-array):

> The new [d3.histogram](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#histograms) API replaces d3.layout.histogram. Rather than
>   exposing `bin.x` and `bin.dx` on each returned bin, the histogram exposes
>   `bin.x0` and `bin.x1`, guaranteeing that `bin.x0` is exactly equal to `bin.x1`
>   on the preceeding bin. The “frequency” and “probability” modes are no
>   longer supported; each bin is simply an array of elements from the
>   input data, so `bin.length` is equal to D3 3.x’s `bin.y` in frequency
>   mode. To compute a probability distribution, divide the number of
>   elements in each bin by the total number of elements.
>
> The `histogram.range` method has been renamed [`histogram.domain`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#histogram_domain) for
>   consistency with scales. The histogram.bins method has been renamed
>   [`histogram.thresholds`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#histogram_thresholds), and no longer accepts an upper value: `n`
>   thresholds will produce `n + 1` bins. If you specify a desired number of
>   bins rather than thresholds, d3.histogram now uses [d3.ticks](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#ticks) to compute
>   nice bin thresholds. In addition to the default Sturges’ formula, D3
>   now implements the [Freedman-Diaconis rule](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#thresholdFreedmanDiaconis) and [Scott’s normal reference rule](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#thresholdScott).

So you should rewrite mentioned code snippet this way:

```
var data = d3.histogram()
  .thresholds(resolution)
  (results);
```

But you also need to rewrite other parts of your code and replace: `d.x+d.dx` to `d.x1`, `d.y` to `d.length` and `d.dx` to `d.x1-d.x0`.

Example how to create histogram layout with d3v4 see in the hidden snippet below:

```js
var data = [
  79, 54, 74, 62, 85, 55, 88, 85, 51, 85, 54, 84, 78, 47, 83, 52, 62, 84, 52, 79, 51, 47, 78, 69, 74, 83, 55, 76, 78, 79, 73, 77, 66, 80, 74, 52, 48, 80, 59, 90, 80, 58, 84, 58, 73, 83, 64, 53,
  82, 59, 75, 90, 54, 80, 54, 83, 71, 64, 77, 81, 59, 84, 48, 82, 60, 92, 78, 78, 65, 73, 82, 56, 79, 71, 62, 76, 60, 78, 76, 83, 75, 82, 70, 65, 73, 88, 76, 80, 48, 86, 60, 90, 50, 78, 63, 72,
  84, 75, 51, 82, 62, 88, 49, 83, 81, 47, 84, 52, 86, 81, 75, 59, 89, 79, 59, 81, 50, 85, 59, 87, 53, 69, 77, 56, 88, 81, 45, 82, 55, 90, 45, 83, 56, 89, 46, 82, 51, 86, 53, 79, 81, 60, 82, 77,
  76, 59, 80, 49, 96, 53, 77, 77, 65, 81, 71, 70, 81, 93, 53, 89, 45, 86, 58, 78, 66, 76, 63, 88, 52, 93, 49, 57, 77, 68, 81, 81, 73, 50, 85, 74, 55, 77, 83, 83, 51, 78, 84, 46, 83, 55, 81, 57,
  76, 84, 77, 81, 87, 77, 51, 78, 60, 82, 91, 53, 78, 46, 77, 84, 49, 83, 71, 80, 49, 75, 64, 76, 53, 94, 55, 76, 50, 82, 54, 75, 78, 79, 78, 78, 70, 79, 70, 54, 86, 50, 90, 54, 54, 77, 79, 64,
  75, 47, 86, 63, 85, 82, 57, 82, 67, 74, 54, 83, 73, 73, 88, 80, 71, 83, 56, 79, 78, 84, 58, 83, 43, 60, 75, 81, 46, 90, 46, 74
];

var width = 952;
var height = 476;
var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([30, 110]).range([0, width]);

var bins = d3.histogram().domain(x.domain()).thresholds(x.ticks(30))(data);

var max = d3.max(bins, function(d) {
  return d.y;
});

var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, .1]).range([0, height]);

var yForHistogram = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(bins, function(d) {
    return d.length;
  })])
  .range([height, 0]);

var vis = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var bars = vis.selectAll("g.bar")
  .data(bins)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.x0) + "," + yForHistogram(d.length) + ")";
  });

bars.append("rect")
  .attr("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("width", x(bins[0].x1) - x(bins[0].x0) - 1)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - yForHistogram(d.length);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```