# JSON, django, d3 error loading array

Tags: json, django, d3.js

I am trying to create a histogram in d3 based on JSON data from my django app. However I keep getting an error. What could be the cause of this?

The errors that I get are the following:

***Chrome***:

> Cannot read property 'histogram' of undefined

***Safari***:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'd3.layout.histogram')

views.py:

```
def chart(request):
Chartdata = serializers.serialize('json', Projects.objects.all(),)
return JsonResponse(Chartdata, safe=False)
```

graphics.html:

```
d3.json(/chart/, function(error, data) {
var x = JSON.parse( data );
var map = x.map(function(i) { return parseInt(i.fields.Totaal); });
console.log(map);

var histogram = d3.layout.histogram()
.bins(25)
(map)
console.log(histogram)
```

The console logs in chrome:

```
(294) [18620730, 24783518, 1931623, 4169495, 4214153, 21594277, 15247677, 4465545, 46921993, 5504440, 4503094, etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found an answer on an other question on this site. The issue is that I was using old code. the working code is the following:

```
d3.json(/chart/, function(error, data) {
var x = JSON.parse( data );
var map = x.map(function(i) { return parseInt(i.fields.Totaal); });
console.log(map);

var histogram = d3.histogram()
.thresholds(25)
(map);
console.log(histogram)
```

see [d3.layout.histogram() and attributes don't work in v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727746/d3-layout-histogram-and-attributes-dont-work-in-v4) for the original answer